# Can I access model tree object data / attributes in Acrobat scripting?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, geospatial, acrobat

I'm looking to write a simple javscript script for Adobe Acrobat that looks through a PDF for "Objects" of the type that are selectable through Tools > Analyze > Object Data Tool and browsable in the "Model Tree", then look at their attributes, and convert them using attribute data.

I've been through the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_Overview.71.1.html) but can't find anything relevant. It's possible that what I'm looking for has a different name. Closest I could find was [`dataObjects and the Data class`](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=Acrobat_SDK_whats_new.14.7.html&accessible=true) but these appear to revolve around  attached files in a PDF portfolio, which is something different.

How can I access the type of attribute-holding interactive objects via scripting that are used with the Analyze > Object Data Tool?

---

It doesn't help that the terms "Object", "Data", "Attribute" and "Model" are so generic. To avoid doubt, this is the type of object data / attributes I want to acccess via scripting, as presented in the Acrobat UI. I want my script to iterate through the items on the top left panel, then for each one, access their attribute properties and values like in the bottom left panel:

[image]

This example is based on a georeferenced map PDF, and this feature of PDFs is often used in PDFs generated by GIS applications like ArcGIS and MapInfo:

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. The 3D player in Acrobat and Reader is actually a separate javascript engine but you can bridge the document JavaScript to the 3D JavaScript and get information from the model. You'll want to review the document linked to below. It's old but the 3D JavaScript hasn't changed since then so it's still valid.

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_3d_api_reference.pdf

The attributes of each node in the model tree are stored as an XML string in the metadataString property of the mesh object. You can get it by accessing the 3D context from the document. Assuming you only have one 3D annotation and it's on the first page you'd use the code below. You can get the mesh by name or by it's index. Just replace getByName() with getByIndex(). Generally, the node name is the same as the name shown in the model tree but not always.

```
var metadata = this.getAnnots3D(0)[0].context3D.scene.meshes.getByName("mesh name").metadataString
```

Then you need to convert the string to an XML object using methods in Acrobat's XMLData object. From there you can use XPath to get at the properties.

Comment: There's also an Acrobat DC version of the JavaScript for Acrobat 3D annotations API Reference from May 2015. I don't remember the URL for it off the top of my head, though.